# Basic Forecast app for iphone

Tags: ios, swift

I was building a basic weather app for iPhone, I am novice in programing, The app gives me one message instead of showing weather, Which is the error message I have written by default, I don't know what's wrong with it, here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var userCity: UITextField!

@IBAction func findWeather(sender: AnyObject) {

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + userCity.text + "/forecasts/latest")

    if url != nil{

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil
            {
                var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

                var urlContentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")

                if urlContentArray.count > 0 {

                    var weatherArray = urlContentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

                    var weather = weatherArray[0] as! String

                    self.resultLabel.text = weather

                }else{
                    self.resultLabel.text = "Was not able to find " + self.userCity.text + "weather. please try again1"
                }   
            }
            else{

            }})
        resultLabel.text = "was not able to find weather " + userCity.text + ". Please try again2"

    }
    else{
        resultLabel.text = "Was not able to find weather" + userCity.text + ". Please try again3"
```

Comment: You should use different message for the different error conditions. Otherwise, debugging will be almost impossible.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? I can't see any logging of an error object.

Comment: @ sebyddd I am not getting a logging error, Just an error in the app, @Chris, I have changed the error message accordingly, Now i am getting error with ending (2)

Comment: Are you sure that the code is still correct? Right now, it seems that the error message ending in 2 is always output because it is not inside the `else` block.